# How to avoid recursion in an update trigger that does an update?

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I need to update the vat_total_sum of goods in a record using a trigger. But the trigger fires to update the record and falls into recursion. How can I avoid this?

The code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vat_total_sum() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN

   UPDATE goods SET vat_total_sum = NEW.vat_sum / 100 * NEW.vat_percent 
      WHERE goods_id = new.goods_id;

RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER vat_total_sum AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON goods
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE vat_total_sum();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use UPDATE, use a `BEFORE` triger and assign the new value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vat_total_sum() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  new.vat_total_sum := NEW.vat_sum / 100 * NEW.vat_percent; 
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER vat_total_sum 
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON goods
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE vat_total_sum();
```